# Is this Xbox 360 Wireless Gaming Receiver legitimate?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, windows

Or is it another knock-off? I know Amazon is reputable but I heard that these receivers were only being produced for sale in a bundle with a 360 controller, not just being sold standalone like this one.

Here is the Amazon page:
[Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HZFCT2)

Here is the original seller's website link: [TotalConsole.com Link](http://www.totalconsole.com/servlet/Categories)

Comment: If you scroll down a little on the Amazon product page to read the reviews it's pretty obvious this is not a genuine Microsoft product - the only question really is if it'll work for you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that, didn't even think to check the reviews...      This question is good to close now.

Comment: I accidentally purchased one of the knockoffs and have found it to be perfectly adequate once successfully installed, but [installation can be tricky](http://www.wtflolomgbbq.com/article/2010/1/20/The-Xbox-360-Wireless-controller-saga). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There's a cheaper knockoff that's around $7, it works just the same and the only difference in setting it up is you manually do it which is incredibly easy.

I have the $7 knockoff one and it works great, I actually have it hooked up via an internal USB header inside my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you dig into the reviews a little further a lot of people are pretty happy with it.  4 stars out of 388 reviews is pretty good.  While it is a knock-off, it does seem legit.  Might be a cheap alternative if you don't mind it not being made by MS.

Comment: Keep in mind that if something *does* go wrong, Microsoft will almost certainly not provide support for this.